# Qual è il senso di "dare la via" in questo brano?

Tags: meaning

Nel libro *Racconto d'autunno*, di Tommaso Landolfi, ho letto:

> Ma pur supponendo che sarei riuscito a forzare una delle porte (colle finestre non c'era speranza perché, tutte quelle almeno
>   che avevo scoperte, erano munite d'inferriata), come ammansare
>   i feroci animali? Mi appigliai a un partito estremo e decisi di sopprimerli, se di meglio non avevo. Ma far fuoco su di loro attraverso il vetro avrebbe significato mancarli quasi certamente, e con
>   grave pericolo, visto che il mio colpo medesimo **avrebbe dato loro la via**, e che il mio fucile, da caccia, non ne aveva più di due; inoltre sarebbe stato un atto troppo aperto d'ostilità contro i misteriosi abitatori, i quali, dopotutto, padroni dei luoghi e delle finestre, potevano colpirmi a loro piacimento e senza nessun rischio, ove avessi manifestato velleità bellicose. Preferibile era
>   dunque per ogni riguardo attirare i cani fuori, e così dare una parvenza di giustificazione alia mia violenza, quasi fossi stato per agire a difesa contro un loro attacco. Tutti questi ragionamenti, lo
>   capisco bene, non erano troppo filati, ma infine furono i miei del
>   momento.

L'io narrante, un uomo che per scampare dalla guerra è in fuga nel bosco, sta cercando disperatamente di entrare in una casa per trovare rifugio, ma ha scoperto che all'interno si trovano due cani feroci.

Ho cercato l'avverbio ["via" nel vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/via1) e una delle accezioni che ho trovato è

> Di qui l’uso di *via* come s. m., per indicare il segnale stesso, nell’espressione *dare il via*, dare il comando della partenza: *era partito prima che il mossiere avesse dato il via; beh, che aspetti a dare il via?*; spesso in senso fig., dare inizio, segnare l’inizio: *il suo comportamento ha dato il via a dicerie e pettegolezzi senza fine; è stato il rifiuto di trattare del datore di lavoro a dare il via alle manifestazioni di protesta*.

È questo il significato dell'espressione "dare la via" nel brano sopra citato, nel senso che il colpo di fucile avrebbe incitato i cani a cominciare a inseguire l'uomo per attaccarlo?

Comment: Infatti, il colpo di fucile avrebbe attirato l'attenzione dei cani e li avrebbe spinti ad attaccare e a dare inizio ad un inseguimento.

Comment: Secondo me il significato può essere interpretato in modo duplice: nel senso di _"dare il via"_ ovvero di incitare i cani oppure di _"indicare la via"_ nel senso che il rumore dello sparo avrebbe indicato ai cani la direzione

Comment: A orecchio, pur non avendo presente questa espressione con “la”, propendo per la seconda ipotesi, cioè che sparando, di fronte a una scarsa probabilità di colpire gli animali, aveva la certezza di tradirsi, di farsi scoprire.

Comment: Un uomo non sarebbe riuscito a entrare per via dell'inferriata, ma un cane ci sarebbe passato, dopo che il colpo di fucile avesse rotto il vetro. Quindi, “dare la via di uscita” per attaccare.

Comment: “Dare la via” significa anche “concedere il passo” (vedi https://books.google.it/books?id=df0sAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA920&dq=%22dare+la+via%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjqsc7BqIfaAhUEbRQKHa7TDVoQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22dare%20la%20via%22&f=false)

Comment: @egreg: Secondo questo dizionario, significa anche "far piazza" che il [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/piazza) definisce come "fare spazio, sgombrare il terreno". Quindi, il colpo di fucile contro i vetri avrebbe sgombrato il terreno ai cani, lasciandoli passare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cani sono chiusi in casa e non possono uscire. Tuttavia, se le inferriate impediscono a un uomo di entrare, forse permettono a un cane di uscire una volta che il vetro sia tolto di mezzo.

Sparare contro un vetro con un fucile da caccia, con la conseguente rosa di pallini, lo frantumerà (una singola pallottola potrebbe solo bucarlo), lasciando così la via libera ai cani per l'assalto contro l'aggressore. Come lo stesso narrante osserva, la rosa di pallini verrebbe ancor più espansa dall'impatto con il vetro, rendendola praticamente inoffensiva per un grosso animale.

“Dare la via”, quindi, nel senso di “concedere il passaggio” o “fare piazza” (vedi [questo dizionario tratto da quello della Crusca nel 1836](https://books.google.it/books?id=df0sAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA920&dq=%22dare%20la%20via%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjqsc7BqIfaAhUEbRQKHa7TDVoQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22dare%20la%20via%22&f=false), ma anche altri).

Sul [Treccani](http://treccani.it/vocabolario/via2/) leggiamo

> *dare la via*, lasciare libero, spec. di andare o di passare (con sign. simile a *dare il via*; v. via<sup>1</sup>, n. 2.

Comment: Grazie, @egreg, ma cos'è la "rosa di pallini"?

Comment: @Charo Vedi [rosata](http://treccani.it/vocabolario/rosata/): una cartuccia contiene pallini di piombo o altro metallo immersi nella polvere da sparo. La detonazione spara i pallini che si espandono a formare uno sciame ovoidale chiamato rosa o rosata. In genere questo tipo di cartucce si usa per i volatili, ma anche per piccoli animali come le lepri.

Comment: Inoltre questa espressione, per quanto spiega il Treccani, si addisce al gusto di Landolfi per termini desueti.